# WooCommerce custom localization address format for specific country

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, format, hook-woocommerce

I am printing address labels from WooCommerce and find that the line breaks for the addresses are not as I need them.

I found the code I need to change in `woocommerce_localisation_address_formats` hook and have added the line break but I do not know enough to add the correct code to the functions file thus avoiding going back to the old format on the next update.

This is the corrected replacement line:

```
'AU' => "{name}\n{company}\n{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{city}\n{state} {postcode}\n{country}",
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `woocommerce_localisation_address_formats` filter hook as follows:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_localisation_address_formats', 'filter_localisation_address_formats' );
function filter_localisation_address_formats( $address_formats ){
    $address_formats['AU'] = "{name}\n{company}\n{address_1}\n{address_2}\n{city}\n{state} {postcode}\n{country}";

    return $address_formats;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.